# homestad Vagrant share website

Tags: laravel, vagrant, share, homestead

I got multiple websites registered with laravel homeasted. Now I use vagrant share option but how can I chose which one of sites gets shared ? Right now I'm trying to share my last project but I'm getting one before that. I even tried deleting other sites from homestead file but I'm still getting my old project for some reason. Just to say my local environment work and I can access this project on project.dev .

homestead.yaml file:

```
  folders:
        - map: C:\Code
          to: /home/vagrant/Code

    sites:
        # - map: project1.dev
        #   to: /home/vagrant/Code/project1/public
        # - map: project2.dev
        #   to: /home/vagrant/Code/project2/public
        - map: project3.dev
          to: /home/vagrant/Code/project3/public
```

Now I can visit project3.dev in my browser but when I share it shares my project2

Comment: Can you show us your .yaml file?

Comment: @Birdman Edited

Comment: Have you run vagrant provision?

Comment: Also, make sure to format your yaml file correctly. The wrong number of spaces can cause it to not work

Comment: @Birdman I did ran provision, and yaml is working I guess since I can access project3.dev just fine